# How to fix Vagrant using invalid URL when trying to download 35-cloud-base box?

Tags: linux, download, vagrant

```
nix-shell:\~/keylime-vagrant-ansible-tpm-emulator\]$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 2.2.19

nix-shell:\~/keylime-vagrant-ansible-tpm-emulator\]$ vagrant up --provision
Bringing machine 'keylime-fedora1' up with 'libvirt' provider...
==\> keylime-fedora1: Box 'fedora/35-cloud-base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
keylime-fedora1: Box Provider: libvirt
keylime-fedora1: Box Version: \>= 0
==\> keylime-fedora1: Loading metadata for box 'fedora/35-cloud-base'
keylime-fedora1: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/fedora/35-cloud-base
==\> keylime-fedora1: Adding box 'fedora/35-cloud-base' (v35.20211026.0) for provider: libvirt
keylime-fedora1: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/fedora/boxes/35-cloud-base/versions/35.20211026.0/providers/libvirt.box
Download redirected to host: dl.fedoraproject.org
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

The requested URL returned error: 404
```

The download link is also broken on this site:
https://app.vagrantup.com/fedora/boxes/35-cloud-base

I tried manual box installation as follows:

```
[nix-shell:~/keylime-vagrant-ansible-tpm-emulator]$ vagrant box add fedora/35-cloud-base
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'fedora/35-cloud-base'
    box: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/fedora/35-cloud-base
This box can work with multiple providers! The providers that it
can work with are listed below. Please review the list and choose
the provider you will be working with.

1) libvirt
2) virtualbox

Enter your choice: 1
==> box: Adding box 'fedora/35-cloud-base' (v35.20211026.0) for provider: libvirt
    box: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/fedora/boxes/35-cloud-base/versions/35.20211026.0/providers/libvirt.box
Download redirected to host: dl.fedoraproject.org
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

The requested URL returned error: 404
```

How fix the URL for this standard vagrant box?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am running into the same problem.